# Textual representation for UML class diagrams - DSL for UML

Tags: uml, dsl

UML classdiagrams are a standard graphical notation to describe classes and their relationships.

Is there a *standard* textual notation (DSL) to describe the same? Don't say XMI or EMF;-)

I think you could do that with Corba IDL and use Interfaces for classes, but this is somehow too much on the Corba side. You could use Java Interfaces, but this is too Java.

Background of my question is writing generators. I think it is easier to write a generator based on the syntax tree of a DSL than to parse a graphical notation. A graphical notation first has to be translated into a syntax tree (that would be the same you'd get from the corresponding DSL). I think translating a graphical notation into the syntax tree is harder than to translate a DSL (where you can use ANTLR).

Comment: What do you expect to be different from XMI or EMF?

Comment: @Doc Brown: Just a guess, but being human readable would probably rate highly...  :-)

Answer (score 12):

You've got the answer already, but I'd like to clarify. There is a **standard** notation, it's called [HUTN](http://www.omg.org/spec/HUTN/), and nobody uses it.

Comment: LOL. Indeed the first time I hear about that. Another OMG product xD

Answer (score 10):

Check this [complete list of textual notations to describe UML models](http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml-tools#textual). Btw, the reasons to create one of these tools (in particular TextUML) can be find [here](http://modeling-languages.com/blog/content/coffee-rafael-chaves-textuml-tool).

Comment: Great, TextUML is exactly what I was thinking of. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is no coincidence that UML separates abstract and concrete syntax.

Tying up code generation to a user-facing notation is a bad idea. Tools (code generators) and people (modelers) have totally distinct needs, so no single syntax can serve both audiences well. Not to mention you lose the ability of applying the same code generator to models created using different notations.

TextUML is a concrete syntax tailored to modelers. XMI is a much better notation for tools, and the UML2 object model makes it very easy to handle.

Rafael

http://abstratt.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

No standard notation to my knowledge but a good summary of options [here](http://modeling-languages.com/blog/content/uml-tools-textual-notations-define-uml-models).

hth.